# How long should it take to load a point layer with readOGR?

Tags: r, time, loading

I am afraid I am quite new to spatial analysis at anything beyond a superficial level, and I have only recently transitioned to utilizing R.  I have been quite pleased with the versatility of areal analysis, but I have just attempted to load my first point layer.

In a nutshell, it's taking much, much longer than anticipated.  I first tried to use [readShapeSpatial](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/maptools/docs/writeSpatialShape) (from maptools I believe), but I read somewhere that [readOGR](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rgdal/docs/ogrInfo) (from rgdal) was faster.  I let readShapeSpatial run for over an hour before killing it, and now readOGR has been running for at least 20 minutes.

Here is the line:

```
c<-readOGR('/home/.../DCSpatialAnalysis','CamaRes.shp')
```

The data attribute houses a frame containing character and numeric data.  There are 106,046 records and 46 columns.  The file size is only ~75MB (including the all elements of the shapefile).

I do not believe my hardware is underpowered for this task (though I am always happy with more horsepower):

> OS: Ubuntu 13.04 (VMWare) on Windows 7
>
> Make/Model: Dell/OptiPlex 790
>
> Processor: i3 (3.3 GHz)
>
> RAM:  16 GB installed

I should mention that I have been able to successfully parse and display an XML document from within my IPython Notebook session that resides in the same directory.  That suggests, to me, that reading from a mounted directory is not an issue.

Have I done something incorrectly here?  R seems to just hang in the "Busy" status, both in RStudio and IPython Notebook (via %rmagic).  How long should such a read in take?

Comment: That does seem too long for a file that size. I am on Windows, but if I have a problem like this I check the R process and kill others that might be using processor time, though my hardware is less powerful than yours. I take it this shapefile is proprietary and thus can't be checked by others?

Comment: Unfortunately you are correct.  We are not allowed to share this information.  However, I have tried some publicly available data, as I describe in the close out to this question below.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I have successfully loaded a publicly available point layer on my home machine (Ubuntu 13.04) fairly quickly.  (I used the CamaResPt.shp layer provided by [DC GIS](http://dcatlas.dcgis.dc.gov/catalog/search_predef.asp)). This leads me to believe that an issue is actually being caused by [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/) (despite my earlier suggestion).  In any event, this question is no longer relevant in its current form.